# Regex expression with special chars and text

Tags: python, regex

Given :

```
str_var ='host="dsa.asd.dsc"port="1234"service_nameORdbName="dsa"pass="dsa"user="ewq"'
```

How to match for example in host's case a stirng that can have abc.dfg.ewq.asd and so on? The data can contain only '.' as special character.

The expression that i got can only match text because w+.

```
    result = re.findall('(\w+)="(\w+)"', str_var)
```

Expected result :

```
[('host':'dsa.asd.dsc'), ('port', '1234'), ('service_nameORdbName', 'dsa'), ('pass', 'dsa'), ('user', 'ewq')]
```

Comment: `print(re.findall('(\w+)="([^"]+)"', str_var))`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/AQHy84)

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: That will allow all characters that are not a quotation mark. Special character other than '.' will be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may either add a `.` to `\w`:

```
result = re.findall('(\w+)="([\w.]+)"', str_var)
```

Or, match `.` delimited words with `\w+(?:\.\w+)*` (one or more word chars followed with 0 or more repetitions of a dot and then one or more word chars):

```
result = re.findall('(\w+)="(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)"', str_var)
```

Or, match values in-between double quotes that may contain anything but a double quote inside (with `"[^"]*"` that matches a `"`, then zero or more chars other than a double quote and then a `"`) :

```
result = re.findall('(\w+)="([^"]+)"', str_var))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/AQHy84).